# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32' when using Generic types

Tags: c#, mysql, console

Today I faced a rather odd problem in my code. I have a MySQL database running on my local machine. In `C#`, I'm using `MySQLConnector` in order to access that database.

I have a function that gets some user data based on the user ID and the column name:

```cs
public T GetUserData<T>(int id, string columnName)
{
    // ...
}
```

In the main method, just to test this function out, I have called it like following:

```cs
int? data = sqlService?.GetUserData<int>(1, "grade");
```

The type of the column `grade` in my database is Int16. Now when I try to cast `Int16` to `int`(`Int32`) in `GetUserData`:

```cs
//       int          Int16
T data = (T)readerSpecific.GetValue(0);
```

It throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32'.'

But I'm very sure that this cast is valid (I've tested it myself using variables of type `int` and `Int16`).

*So what's the problem here?* I assume it's due to some Generic stuff, but I'd love to know more.
Thanks!

Comment: Try using `readerSpecific.GetFieldValue<T>(0)`.